# C# animation alternative

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, animation, mouse

I am trying to get 2 Ellipses to move on screen(canvas) with coordinates from 2 Wiimote devices . Pretty much like a mouse would behave . The coordinates will need to be recorded so it would be best if that can be done after the animation method . So far i tryed with TranslateTransform but the Ellipses were mooving extremely glitchy and not appropriate for user experience . Also I tryed using PointAnimation and Storyboard but the problem is that the coordinates are not preset and the method is called each time a WiimoteChanged event is fired , so in the second method the point are not mooving at all since the event is fired several hundred times per second .

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change ellipse position by changing either its parent position, or its offset relative to parent. I've created small example, where red ellipse is following mouse cursor and it looks fine to me.
You should probably look in direction of adorners at some moment, to not interfere with main visual tree of your app.
Here is the code. Just place it in newly created mainwindow.

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Content = new TestEllipse();
        }

        public class TestEllipse : Canvas
        {
            private Ellipse MyEllipse;
            public TestEllipse()
            {
                MyEllipse = new Ellipse() { StrokeThickness = 1, Fill = Brushes.Red, Height = 100, Width = 100 };
                this.Children.Add(MyEllipse);
                this.Loaded += TestEllipse_Loaded;
            }

            void TestEllipse_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                var wnd = GetWindow(this);
                wnd.MouseMove += wnd_MouseMove;
            }

            void wnd_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                var coords = e.GetPosition(sender as Window);
                Canvas.SetLeft(MyEllipse, coords.X - MyEllipse.Width / 2);
                Canvas.SetTop(MyEllipse, coords.Y - MyEllipse.Height / 2);
            }
        }
    }
```